# Codeigniter 4 - how to redirect to another controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, routes

This problem has lots of threads, still I haven't found one to fully resolve my issue. Many of the threads concern older versions of CodeIgniter, I currently have CodeIgniter version 4.3.1. I also use HMVC setup, where I want to have a subfolder App\Modules where I'm keeping modules like "auth" for authentication and "home" for dashboards and user specific pages

My goal is to create a simple login where, once logged successfully, I am pointed at a dashboard page.

The problem I have is that in my login controller, if the authentication is successful I have a redirect to /home/dashboard  but that errors out either because I have no (or invalid) route or it screws the link and points me back to default controller.

Here are an extract of the main related components in my files:

**\App\Modules\auth\Controllers\Login.php:** (Controller)

```
<?php namespace app\Modules\auth\Controllers;
class Login extends \CodeIgniter\Controller
{
        ...
    public function attempt()
        {
              ...
              //if success
              $resp = redirect()->to("home/dashboard);
              ...
        }
        ...
}
```

**\App\Modules\home\Controllers\Dashboard.php:** (Dashboard controller)

```
<?php namespace app\Modules\home\Controllers;
use \CodeIgniter\Controller;
class Dashboard extends Controller
{
      ...
      public function index()
      {
             ...
             return view('\App\Modules\home\Views\dashboard', $data)

      }
}
```

**\App\Config\Routes.php:**

```
<?php
namespace Config;
$routes = Services::routes();
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Modules');
$routes->setDefaultController('company\Controllers\Home');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('index');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override();
//$routes->setAutoRoute(true);

...

/* auth routes */
$routes->get('auth/login', 'auth\Controllers\Login::index');
$routes->get('auth/login/(:any)', 'auth\Controllers\Login::index/$1');
$routes->post('auth/login/attempt', 'auth\Controllers\Login::attempt');

/* home */
$routes->get('/home/dashboard', 'home\Controllers\Dashboard::index');

if (is_file(APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php')) {
    require APPPATH . 'Config/' . ENVIRONMENT . '/Routes.php';
}
```

Once I log in successfully I am redirected to this URL that only shows the default container:
`http://localhost/ci4/public/index.php?%2Fhome%2Fdashboard=`
it should at least show or act as
`http://localhost/ci4/public/index.php/home/dashboard`

Please let me know what prevents me to see the App\Modules\home\Controllers\Dashboard controller and the view it calls...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After attempts I found out a way:
so instead of

```
 $resp = redirect()->to("home/dashboard);
```

to use

```
return redirect()->redirect("/ci4/home/dashboard");
```

To me this sounds like a CI4.3.1 bug rather than a feature. To call Redirect from Redirect looks like a confusing design.

I'm posting this in case it helps anyone

Comment: No it is not a bug! It is the new way of running things in codeigniter 4. It says it right here - https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=redirect#redirect